# Encountered the symbol "THEN" when expecting one of the following

Tags: oracle

Encountered the symbol "THEN" when expecting one of the following:     * & - + ; / at mod remainder rem  and or ||    multiset

```
CASE
         WHEN CLAIMNUMBER = 311754 AND POLICY_NUMBER = 21620 THEN             cast(CLAIMNUMBER as varchar2(10)) + 'M'
                   WHEN CLAIMNUMBER = 317802 AND POLICY_NUMBER = 15571 THEN    cast(CLAIMNUMBER as varchar2(10)) + 'M'
                 WHEN CLAIMNUMBER = 318794 AND POLICY_NUMBER = 19325 THEN cast(CLAIMNUMBER as varchar2(10)) + 'M'
         WHEN CLAIMNUMBER = 319510 AND POLICY_RECORD_ID = '21294_19' THEN cast(CLAIMNUMBER as varchar2(10)) + 'M'
            ELSE
                cast(CLAIMNUMBER as varchar(10))
            END AS CLAIMNUMBER,
```

Comment: Please check `cast(CLAIMNUMBER as varchar2(10)) + 'M'`
In Oracle PL SQL or SQL, concatenate syntax is `||` and not `+`. Also, is this part of a bigger sql query? can you please share full query?

Comment: Also, please tell us data types of `CLAIMNUMBER `

Comment: Why do you use `cast` not `to_char`?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `CLAIMNUMBER` is numeric data type, the most likely cause for this issue is use of `+` as concatenation operator. Instead use`||` to concatenate strings and your query should work fine. refined query should look like below

```
select CASE
          WHEN CLAIMNUMBER = 311754 AND POLICY_NUMBER = 21620 THEN  cast(CLAIMNUMBER as varchar2(10))  'M'
          WHEN CLAIMNUMBER = 317802 AND POLICY_NUMBER = 15571 THEN  cast(CLAIMNUMBER as varchar2(10)) || 'M'
          WHEN CLAIMNUMBER = 318794 AND POLICY_NUMBER = 19325 THEN  cast(CLAIMNUMBER as varchar2(10)) || 'M'
          WHEN CLAIMNUMBER = 319510 AND POLICY_RECORD_ID = '21294_19' THEN cast(CLAIMNUMBER as varchar2(10)) || 'M'
          ELSE
                  cast(CLAIMNUMBER as varchar2(10))
        END AS CLAIMNUMBER1
```